# MYSQL Beginner. Creating tables with columns of multiple data types

Tags: mysql, sql, generics, import-from-csv

I am importing a CSV into an SQL database but the columns in my CSV can have multiple data types such as a "Number_of_people" column of integers containing string values of "N/A".

From what I have seen table creation involves specifying the datatypes of the columns, such as

```
CREATE TABLE sampletable( Number_of_people INT );
```

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making it a VARCHAR and then when retrieving that data, convert the string to a int

Answer (score 1):

I would make the column nullable and convert 'N/A' into NULL when the data is inserted.